# How to hide a UIView while scrolling?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiview, uiscrollview

I am trying to achieve this effect.

[image]

I am trying to hide a view, as the user scrolls up, and reveal it as the user scrolls down.

I do not know how to go about this.
I have tried looking as the scrollView didScroll function, but I am lost as how to set this up. Any advice?

Comment: Show what have you done so far ?

Comment: Also confirm, is your view simple UIView or tableView or collectionView ?

Comment: My bet would be to remember last the `contentOffset` of the `scrollView` in the `didScroll` method. Then if you see that `scrollView` goes up you shall move (animate) your custom` view` up to the some point (as I see together with alpha). When you notice it goes down do the oposite (also limited to the some point).

Comment: @cole i have not done any thing because i literally do not even know where to start. You guys do not have to give me a code answer. I can figure that out. What i need it how i would go about doing it.

Comment: @cole even my google searching was difficult. Do i search for "hiding header"? I am not sure what this is even called. I am using a UICollectionView. But i'll also take an explanation of a UITableView. I think they are both UIScrollView subclasses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Hiding content on scroll](https://github.com/telly/TLYShyNavBar)

Please check this library it do exactly what your attached gif do.

The other way around would be from the gif file attached by you would be.
Add search bar on top. And make hiding part as  a header and aligned the search bar and tableview to get that animation.

Answer (score 4):

I solved like this:

```
private var lastContentOffset: CGFloat = 0

func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
   lastContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
}

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if lastContentOffset > scrollView.contentOffset.y {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: { [weak self] in
            self?.addDeviceButton.alpha = 1.0
            self?.addDeviceButton.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: 1.0)
        }, completion: nil)
    } else if lastContentOffset < scrollView.contentOffset.y {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: { [weak self] in
            self?.addDeviceButton.alpha = 0
            self?.addDeviceButton.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up the container view for the scroll view and the view you want to hide as the delegate for the scroll view, registering this class to conform to the UIScrollViewDelegate protocol.

You also need to keep track of the scroll view’s content offset property, and setvthis to the initial offset of the scroll view when it is created:

```
fileprivate var scrollOffset : CGPoint
```

Then, as you say, use the scrollViewDidScroll method:

```
internal func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let delta : CGPoint = CGPoint(x: scrollView.contentOffset.x - scrollOffset.x, 
        y: scrollView.contentOffset.y - scrollOffset.y)

    if delta.y > 0, subviewToFade.isDescendant(of: self) {
           // fade out subviews and remove
    else if delta < 0, !subviewToFade.isDescendant(of: self) {
           // add subviews and fade back in

    }

    scrollOffset = scrollView.contentOffset
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

[here is my constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4sNa.png)

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    setPosition(scrollView)
}

func setPosition(_ scrollView:UIScrollView) {

    if scrollView.contentOffset.y >= 20 {
        self.parentTopViewcontraints.constant = -95 // set postition till you want to hide your view 
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }else if scrollView.contentOffset.y <= 200 {
        self.parentTopViewcontraints.constant = 0 //set back 
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please provide a brief explanation of what this code does and how it solves the problem in the question.